# Why doesn't my Raycast2Ds detect walls from my tilemap

Tags: godot

I am currently trying to make a small top-down RPG with grid movement.
To simplify things, when i need to make something move one way, I use a RayCast2D Node and see if it collides, to know if i can move said thing.
However, it does not seem to detect the walls ive placed until I am inside of them.

Ive already checked for collision layers, etc and they seem to be set up correctly.
What have i done wrong ?

More info below :

Heres the code for the raycast check :

```
func is_path_obstructed_by_obstacle(x,y):
    $Environment_Raycast.set_cast_to(Vector2(GameVariables.case_width * x * rayrange, GameVariables.case_height * y * rayrange))
    return $Environment_Raycast.is_colliding()
```

My walls are from a TileMap, with collisions set up. Everything that uses collisions is on the default layer for now

Also heres the function that makes my character move :

```
func move():
    var direction_vec = Vector2(0,0)
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_right"):
        direction_vec = Vector2(1,0)
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_left"):
        direction_vec = Vector2(-1,0)
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
        direction_vec = Vector2(0,-1)
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_down"):
        direction_vec = Vector2(0,1)
    
    if not is_path_obstructed(direction_vec.x, direction_vec.y):
        position += Vector2(GameVariables.case_width * direction_vec.x, GameVariables.case_height * direction_vec.y)
        grid_position += direction_vec
    
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ray casts always make sure it is `enabled`.

Just in case, I'll also mention that the ray cast `cast_to` is in the ray cast local coordinates.

Of course collision layers apply, and the ray cast has `exclude_parent` enabled by default, but I doubt that is the problem.

Finally, remember that the ray cast updates on the physics frame, so if you are using it from `_process` it might be giving you outdated results. You can call call `force_update_transform` and `force_raycast_update` on it to solve it. Which is also what you would do if you need to move it and check multiple times on the same frame.

---

For debugging, you can turn on collision shapes in the debug menu, which will allow you to see them when running the game, and see if the ray cast is positioned correctly. If the ray cast is not enabled it will not appear. Also, by default, they will turn red when they collide something.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know that Raycasts updated on the _physics frame, i used force_raycast_update and it solved the problem !